# How to get Table Stats of Hive table into Dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a project on Spark scala
Can I get table stats of a Hive table into a Dataframe for further calculations?

I could see info of the table using

"show table stats table_name"

But can I get that info into a dataframe.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough.

```
val df = spark.sql("show table stats table_name")
```

But, my test for table stats not worked. I used an `ANALYZE` and `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` for the test.

```
spark.sql("analyze table table_name compute statistics")
val df = spark.sql("describe extended table_name")
df.show(false)
```

This gives a result.

Answer (score 0):

In spark2, you can import hive table data into data frames in either of below methods:

Method1:

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from databasename.tablename")
```

Method2:

```
val df = spark.read.table("databasename.tablename")
```